# Rewrite url in CakePhp

Tags: cakephp

I'm new to Cakephp.

I have a home page with a lot of links like `/mark-james.hmtl`...`/steve-pain.html`, etc.
I want to display the personal page after the user clicks on the name, how can rewrite that?
Obviously now I have: `Error: mark-james.hmtlController could not be found`.

Comment: use routes and generate urls by Router Class..

Answer (score 0):

```
Router::connect(
    '/user1-home-page',
    array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'user1')
);
```

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html

You can define routing as mentioned above.